# why pn junction turn ON for lower voltages at higher temperatures?

Tags: pn-junction

Increase in temperature produces electron-hole pairs. So number of holes created due to temperature equal to number electrons I believe. If you apply some voltage there will be equal number of majority and minority carrier generated due to temperature hence they should balance each other and there should not be any shifts in characteristic curve. But curve shifts to left (knee voltage reduces to lower voltages as temperature increases) why?

Comment: Increased carrier mobility. Temperature = motion.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181995/why-does-temperature-modify-the-characteristics-of-a-diode

Answer (score 1):

In a cold semiconductor below the knee voltage electrons from the *n* side haven’t enough energy to enter the *p* side and, likewise, holes from the *p* side haven’t enough energy to enter the *n* side. When you heat it, a large fraction of charge carriers (on one of these sides, or both) acquire necessary energy. The [Fermi–Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Distribution_of_particles_over_energy) can provide an approximation, although forward-biased junction is a strongly non-equilibrium system.

In terms of the [Shockley diode equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/120612/118355), it is described as “the saturation current \$I_{\mathrm S}\$ increases with \$T\$ faster than \$\exp(V_{\mathrm D} / n V_T)\$ decreases”.

Answer (score 0):

Quote Incnis Mrsi`s answer: "*In terms of the Shockley diode equation, it is described as “the saturation current IS increases with T faster than exp(VD/nVT) decreases*”."

Yes - correct. Perhaps it is helpful to be somewhat more detailed.

The saturation current Is - and, hence, also the collector current Ic - increases with temperature. However, because the temperature dependence of the Ic=f(Vbe) characteristic is specified for a CONSTANT Ic, the voltage Vbe must be reduced correspondingly to keep Ic=const. This leads to a reduction in Vbe given by a negative tempco; d(Vbe)/dT=-2mV/K.

That means: Vbe does not (automatically) become smaller with rising temperatures, but it must externally reduced to keep Ic practically constant. For such a reduction we can use an external emitter resistor RE.