# The forward voltage Vf of a diode

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, device

I want to know about the forward voltage \$V_{f}\$ parameter of a diode device, given an I-V charateristic curve and in ambient temperature. What is the criteria to define the \$V_{f}\$ for any diode? How can I define it if I work with this 
 current expression \$i_D = I_s (\exp^{v_D/V_{th}}-1)\$?
Sometimes I see the value of this parameter like \$V_{f}=0.7\ \mbox{V}\$ for some type of diode, but how can I calculate given any \$i_D\$ expression?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. By Von I assume you mean the forward voltage drop. By criteria I assume you mean ambient temperature and forward current. Give us a few clues please.

Comment: Hi @Sparky256 , thanks for your time, and sorry for my english. I edited the post. I mean about, given a I-V curve of the diode, how can I define the \$V_{on}\$? What is the criteria to build this parameter?

Comment: Read this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/120612/27943

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y5eycqgq. Above 1 to 10mA the Rs bulk resistance dominates the exponential depending on power rating,size

Answer (score 1):

**If this is a small signal silicon diode, then use Vf=0.6V @ 1mA**

But reducing the current by a log scale also reduces the forward voltage on a linear scale up to 5 decades down. Above this, the bulk resistance limits the minimum resistance and thus voltage rise with the current before its power limit.

For Power diodes, the internal bulk resistance limits the rise in voltage where they are rated for Vf at Idc(max).

For specific diode VI graphs, one needs a part number or datasheet below *and* above 1 mA.  There are several non-ideal factors [but common curves are available on the web.](https://www.google.com/search?q=diode%20vi%20log%20scale&num=50&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlgcDii9DdAhViylQKHT56BqgQsAR6BAgFEAE&biw=724&bih=739#imgrc=WtOwGf087jD4xM:)

[For Engineering details](http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/Diode.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

"*What is the criteria to define the Vf for any diode? How can I define it if I work with this current expression iD=Is(expvD/Vth−1)? Sometimes I see the value of this parameter like Vf=0.7 V for some type of diode, but how can I calculate given any iD expression?*"

The forward voltage of a pn-diode (and this applies to the B-E path of a BJT as well) is not and cannot be "defined". As you correctly have noticed, there is a certain relationship between current and voltage (exponential function, involving also the temperature voltage).

However, because of the temperature dependence and the tolerance properties of the factor Is, the actual values for If and Vf are normally not known. On the other hand, the exponential characteristic is relatively "steep" so that the voltage Vf - for most applications - will be between Vf=0.6...0.7 volts.

It is, therefore, common practice to assume a value within this range for calculation purposes during design of corresponding circuits. That means, there is no commonly agreed forward voltage, but a suitable value will be assumed - for small currents (< 1mA) perhaps 0.6 volts and for larger currents (>5mA) perhaps 0,7 volts.